# How does array.inject(:+) work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know hash.map(&:key) function like hash.map{|element| element.key} because it call the to_proc on the symbol :key.

But why does array.inject(:+) work same as array.inject{|sum,x| sum + x }?

Thank you.

Comment: it's just a shortcut...

Comment: `map` and `inject` are not the same thing, so it is not surprising that they work differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the sole argument to `inject` is not a symbol, it is used as the initial value, otherwise, `to_proc` and `&` are applied to the argument, and that is used as a block. When there are two arguments, the first one is used as the initial value, and the second one must be a symbol, and would be used to create a block as described above.

A drawback of this is that you cannot use a symbol as the initial value of `inject`, but it is probably considered that there is no use case for that. I don't think this specification is clean.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Your reasoning "there are not any" [that you can do with them] is what I mean that there is no use case for that. Immutable is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think the symbol is used to create a block. I have a feeling something like this happens: `initial.method(:+).call(next)`. Also, a good place to find information on this is in the documentation. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Answer (score 1):

```
array.inject(:+)
```

In the ruby `inject` method, when no block is passed in, it looks if the first argument is a symbol (i.e. `:+`) for the method to use. In this case it will recognize `:+` as a symbol and know it needs to sum the entire list.

It is possible to use

```
array.inject(&:+)
```

which will call `to_proc` first and is slightly more inefficient.

You may want to use

```
array.inject(0, :+)
```

To return 0 (instead of nil) in the case where your array is of length 0. In this case your first argument is not a symbol, and so Ruby will look at the second argument for the method to use.